# Server url in Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, whatsapp, whatsapi

I use Whatsapp Business API and started 3 docker images to do it. But I don't know url to make requests. I tried `0.0.0.0:9090`, `127.0.0.1:9090`, `localhost:9090` but nothing works. How can I know right url?

Under docker containers I add attach image. And as stackoverflow restricts me to post question I need add some text "water".

[image]

Here is a file with settings `docker-compose.yml`
version: '3'

```
volumes:
  whatsappMedia:
    driver: local
  mysqlData:
    driver: local
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7.35
     restart: always
     environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testpass
        MYSQL_USER: testuser
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: testpass
     expose:
        - "33060"
    ports:
    - "33060:3306"
volumes:
 - mysqlData:/var/lib/mysql
network_mode: bridge
cap_drop:
  - MKNOD
wacore:
 image: docker.whatsapp.biz/coreapp:v${WA_API_VERSION:-2.35.5?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.37.1 docker-compose <command> <options>)}
command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_mysql.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
volumes:
 - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
env_file:
  - db.env
environment:
  # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
  WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
  ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
depends_on:
  - "db"
network_mode: bridge
links:
  - db
cap_drop:
  - MKNOD
waweb:
image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v${WA_API_VERSION:-2.35.4?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.37.1 docker-compose <command> <options>)}
command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_mysql.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
ports:
 - "9090:443"
volumes:
 - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
env_file:
  - db.env
environment:
  WACORE_HOSTNAME: wacore
  # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
  WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
  ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
depends_on:
  - "db"
  - "wacore"
links:
  - db
  - wacore
network_mode: bridge
cap_drop:
  - MKNOD
```

Comment: @JRichardsz Don't if know if you this. Thanks for helping me, I attached yml. Question is closed by stackoverflow, that is why I reopened it.

Comment: It looks like your YAML file lost a lot of its indentation; can you edit this to correct it?  You also have several unnecessary (`network_mode:`, `expose:`) and obsolete (`links:`) options, and removing these might help you get to a [mcve].  What's your host OS?  Is the container process (the `waweb` container?) listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address?  What's a specific URL you're trying to connect to, and what error do you get?  What is the PNG file you included in the question?

Comment: @Davide Maze, thanks for replying. Png is the file to show images I run and all of them are "Up". Container process is a water container. I just copied all settings from WhatsApp docs. Firstly, it worked and then it started to show error that database is sleeping 